# Interface that is optionally callable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsc

I have a use case where I create a bound function with data on it, or I just use an object.

So now I have this interface:

```
export interface LMLockSuccessData  {
  (err: any, v: LMLockSuccessData): void 
  acquired: boolean,
  lockUuid: string,
  id: string
}
```

in some case I use:

```
const fn = foo.bind(this, 'bar');
fn.id = 'bar';
fn.lockUuid = null;
fn.acquired = true;
```

or I just do:

```
{id: 'bar', lockUuid: null, acquired: true}
```

so my question is, is there a way to make this line optional in the interface?

```
export interface LMLockSuccessData  {
  (err: any, v: LMLockSuccessData): void  // make this optional? 
  acquired: boolean,
  lockUuid: string,
  id: string
}
```

using a question mark, doesn't work:

```
  (err: any, v: LMLockSuccessData)?: void
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct such a type as follows. First part is the interface containing ordinary properties:

```
interface P {
    acquired: boolean,
    lockUuid: string,
    id: string
}
```

Then the function type:

```
interface F {
    (err: any, v: LMLockSuccessData): void
}
```

Finally, create the type that is either the properties *or* the combination of properties with the function.

```
type LMLockSuccessData = P | (P & F);
```

However I'm not sure how useful any of this is right now with your use case. Note that `bind` is not currently strongly typed. It uses `any`. [TypeScript is likely to fix this soon](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).

But even then, the typing may be quite unhelpful. If you write a type intending it to be `(P & F)`-compatible, but you get the function declaration wrong (e.g. missing or extra parameters or wrong return type), then it will still be `P`-compatible. So incorrect functions will be compatible, precisely because you made the function optional, and *extra* function overloads are permissible (they are ignored).